# What are the mathematical reasons for requiring sigma-additivity for probability measures?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

My question is regarding the third axiom of probability that requires that probability measures are sigma additive, i.e., that any countable sequence $A_1, A_2,  ... $ of disjoint sets satisfies
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_i). $$

Kolmogorov himself wrote in his foundations of the theory of probability that "we limit ourselves, arbitrarily" to measures that are sigma additive. So my question is why this is so convenient from a mathematical perspective?

This question is not meant to discuss this axiom from a philosophical point of view or its shortcomings but rather why the sigma additivity is useful to develop further the theory of probability?

Some arguments that I have come across, and that I would like to understand are:

1.) It is needed to use integration/measure theory (e.g. to compute expectations). Why do we need sigma additivity for that?

2.) It makes every borel set measureable once we know open sets are measurable. How? The way I learned the definition of a measurable set, it is just a set in the sigma algebra. So every Borel set is by definition measurable. For that we dont even need a measure.

3.) It is required to proof e.g. the law of large numbers. Why?

I would be glad if anyone could explain the above points and I am also happy if anyone can come up with more points that are not yet in the above list.

Comment: [[1]] Might be more convenient to list the Axiom(s) here. You ( & the answer by user stas ) mention Axiom 3 , while this Paper ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606533.pdf ) mentions Axiom 6 , which is a little confusing. Explicitly listing it here will make it easier & self-contained. [CONTINUED-]

Comment: [-CONTINUED] [[2]] That Paper gave clues on the Case : (A) ".... we limit ourselves arbitrarily to models that satisfy Axiom VI. So far this **limitation has been found
expedient** in the most diverse investigations" (B) "Borel .... had **not encountered** circumstances where its rejection seemed expedient" (C) "Kolmogorov articulated .... the **purely instrumental significance** of infinity"

Comment: [-CONTINUED] [[3]] This Paper compares the **Original "6-Axiom Case"** with the **"3-Axiom Case"** , thus throwing more light on the matter. ( https://win-vector.com/2020/09/19/kolmogorovs-axioms-of-probability-even-smarter-than-you-have-been-told/ )

Answer (score 1):

Sigma-additivity of measures (the third axiom) is essential in order to prove the continuity of probability, i.e. if $A_n$ is a sequence of decreasing event, then $P(\cap A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$.

Without this, for example, we lose most of the properties of the CDF $F_X(x)=P(X\le x)$ of a random variable $X$, such as
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty} F(x)=0;\
\lim_{x\to+\infty} F(x)=1;\
\lim_{x\downarrow a} F(x)=F(a)
$$
as well as lots of other important properties.

Comment: Maybe relevant: In fact, for probability measures, having sigma additivity is equivalent to having finite additivity plus the continuity property that you mention.

Comment: can you also comment on why it is required for integration ect?

Comment: Imagine that $\Omega=[0,1]$ with the standard Borel sigma-algebra ${\cal F}$. Let $X(\omega)=1$ if $\omega$ is rational, and $=0$ otherwise, and the probability measure is such that for any interval $[a,b]$ we have ${\mathbb P}([a,b])=b-a$. With sigma-additivity, we can conclude that ${\mathbb E}(X)=0$ as we can sum (infinitely!) over a countable set of rational, each having measure $0$. Without this, we cannot find the expectation (i.e. integrate).